# What SQL Server DataType Should I Store an Email MessageId As?

Tags: sql-server, email, messageid

I'm writing a feature that processes inbound/outbound emails and stores them. One of the most important pieces that I need to store is the `Message-Id` that's in the header of all standard-compliant emails (from what I understand).

I was going to store the entire `Message-Id` in a field and index on it, but as I started digging into that, it seems to be the wrong approach. I plan on splitting the `Message-Id` at the `@` sign and storing each piece in a `MessageIdLocalPart` and `MessageIdDomain` respectively, then index on the local part.

I've read where the max length for the local part of an email address is `64` characters, and the max for the domain is `255`. Now, these max lengths seem to be for email addresses, and I don't see any max lengths in the standard for `Message-Id`, so I'm not sure that the same restriction applies.

I understand that, as always, there will be non-compliant emails that come through. I'm just going to omit those. I'm working with **compliant only** emails.

So, instead of storing the local part and domain pieces as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, is there a better limit and/or data type that I should be using?

Comment: Are you going to store a 2GB Message-Id? That's what `varchar(max)` is for.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do I need to accommodate for a 2GB Message-Id? I don't know if the standard 64/255 length restrictions are the same for Message-Ids.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Great - thank you.